# UIApplication openURL can not open a url

Tags: uitableview, nsstring, nsurl, uiapplication, openurl

I'm trying to implement a job search App. The results are shown to the user in a UITableView.
When a user clicks on a cell, it should open the original Job announcement.
To do this, i implemented the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc]init];
    url=[[[xmlParser jobs] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] urlAddress]; //UrlAddress is an instance variable of type NSString
    NSURL *urlJobDetail = [NSURL URLWithString:(url)];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: urlJobDetail];
}
```

The interesting part is: if i type an NSString like @"http://www.google.com" or any other link, it works. But when i try to open a "the urlJobDetail", it just doesn't work... Nothing happens at all...

And i searched it in stackoverflow.com and found this:

```
url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Than the url works but this method changes the original url address and adds lots of % signs like: 
"http://www.google.com%20 %20 %20"
So i get an page not found error.

I don't understand why this function doesn't accept a regular NSString variable as?

I checked it with NSLog and the url seems to be perfectly in order.

Any help would be much, very much appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Because it's [URL specification](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt) related restrictions

> Spaces and control characters in URLs must be escaped for transmission in HTTP, as must other disallowed characters... It is necessary to encode any characters disallowed in a URL, including spaces and other binary data not in the allowed character set, using the standard convention of the "%" character followed by two hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer but i don't fully get it... If the escape changes the URL and so that i can not open the URL that I want, how does that help me ? Is there a way to open the URL ?